# 'PrematureCloseException: Connection premium closed DURING response' occurs when using WebClient

Tags: rest, netty, webclient

In normal cases, WebClient works well, but an exception occurs on particular api call.
The error log is as follows.

```
reactor.core.Exceptions$ReactiveException: reactor.netty.http.client.PrematureCloseException: Connection prematurely closed DURING response
```

Why is this happening?
Is there an API that is not supported WebClient calls?